# Numerical integration - midpoint rule

Tags: python, numerical-integration

Hello I'm trying to solve an exercise and am not quite sure how to properly code it. I think matlab might be easier for this but I don't really know that language so I tried python, as it should technically also work. (I'm also not very good at it though)

I have to approximate an integral on the interval [0,1] , given the function f, n (amount of midpoints) and the exact value of the integral I(f).

The output should be the approximation Q and the error E (difference between Q and the exact result I(f)

The midpoint rule is defined as follows: 1/n * sum_i=1 to n f_i ,with f_i = f((2i-1)/2n)

I have just tried some simple code in python to maybe get a result but I already got the wrong result on a quite simple function.

```
    
def F(x):
    return x**2

def Qn(f,n,I):
    q = sum(f((2*i-1)/(2*n))/n for i in range(1,n+1))
    error = abs(I-q)
    return "Q = {} , error = {}".format(q,error)
        
Qn(F,1,1/3)
```

The reason I defined F(x) first was so that I could just use a simple function of x^2.
I think the problem lies in the for loop, as I'm not quite sure if it even approximates it closer, or actually just adds more terms as I have not specified that the integral is from 0 to 1.

I know this code looks terrible and is extremely inefficient, however I am not quite sure how to properly code this.

Edit: I edited the code with the help from the comments. I think it's working fine. Is there a way to make this for general functions in python without specifying first?

Comment: `(2*i-1)/2*n` should be `(2*i-1)/2/n` or `(2*i-1)/(2*n)`.

Comment: @PaulHankin You're right! I do not know how I missed that. Thank you very much! May I ask how I can apply this function to general functions, without defining them first in a different function?

Comment: BTW, your loop runs from i=0 to i=n. That's not quite right. Also, your code doesn't print any output. Your code doesn't look terrible, but I think it'd be better for the Qn function to just do the summation, and do the error stuff outside the function. But if you *do* want to do the error calculation in the function, just `return q, error` and do the formatting in the calling code.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh yes you're right it should be from i=1 to i=n , I'll change that. I'll try to implement the built in sum function. How would that look like though? sum(f((2*i-1)/(2*n))/n for i in range(1,n+1)?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes that's true. I usually have to create a separate file just to test it sometimes. I'm never quite sure if the endpoints are included. I have now edited the question so that the code should be more correct.

Comment: @PM2Ring The task was to implement a function that takes a given function and approximates the integral. I just chose x^2 since it was easy to define. But given only my function Qn , is there a way to use it for all functions. My guess is that I could use import math and then use math.function . I'm not sure if this limitation is due to python. Maybe matlab could implement such a thing?

Comment: I *think* you can assume that the function to be integrated will be supplied as a normal Python function, just like your `F`. If you want to pass a function to the program as a string, eg from a command line argument, that's also possible, but it's generally discouraged because it creates a security hole: the passed-in function can do anything, including evil stuff, like formatting your hard drive. Of course, that's only an issue if the program is accessible to malicious users. For details, see [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: @PM2Ring I see. I was just not quite sure as I could not just put in a polynomial for f without using lambda. But I guess using that makes it simpler. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry to bother again. I think the exercise is correct so far. So I tried to work on a different subtask but it seems to me that I made some big mistakes again. Should I just post a new question or is there an easier way to just ask these questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231818/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-23408924).